# ADVENT Container - Loot recovery?

Tags: xcom-2

As some of you may have noticed, there some non-mission-related containers that can be found and opened during some missions types.

[image]

They can be interacted with while standing on any square around them. When "opened", the following loot message appears:

[image]

So far, I opened three of those containers, but they never contained anything. I digged through some other threads where those crates were mentioned, and while some people claim that they revovered some loot from them, I haven't found any evidence yet. Two sources mentioned recovering a "datapad".

Maybe this was some early loot mechanism, that was abandoned before the final release?

Does anyone have more information on this?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Never noticed those before. Good catch. Curious to see answers.

Comment: I am pretty sure I've recovered a datapad from one of them, on a "Rescue VIP from Advent City" mission. That was in a version after launch, before first DLC.

Comment: I've never seen anything in the pop when looting, but after the mission ends, I have items that can't be accounted for from other loot sources. I'm inclined to believe that the containers work, they just don't show properly.

Comment: @ChrisHayes: What kind of items? I find it hard to believe that its a bug, because it should be obvious to play testers and developers (if they expect something to show up there). I also don't think that it is some kind of design decision NOT to show what was recovered, at least I see no reason why. Maybe you have a save game where you can reproduce that you recovered something? I haven't noticed any additional loot at the end of the missions after opening such a container.

Comment: I don't have any saves that are near loot containers unfortunately. The loot is the same stuff I would typically get off enemies - elerium cores, weapon mods, that sort of thing.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen these before and opened them a number of times.

On each occasion the box is visually empty - as in your screenshot. But the audio of the solider says "there is some loot here" and there is a sound of items been scooped up.

I just did a VIP extraction mission on L/I - and I noticed I had an "extra" item at the end. I had 2x repeaters, an elerium core, and a scope. That is 4 items, but I only ever get a max of 3 from an alien drop.

So I can assume at this point the 4th item came from the chest. This would imply you get a "random" item from the chest at this stage...

**Edit:** I can now confirm - you **do** receive "random" items from the container. I just completed a mission, and received an extra "Laser Sight" and "Hair Trigger" mods that were extra to what I had picked up in the mission.

Comment: I am not sure if 3 is the maximum number of items from a regular loot drop (assuming you have "Vulture"). Somewhere else i read it could be up to 5 but I can't confirm that and don't find the source. Maybe its something we could find in the config files. I concur with your observations about the sounds.

Comment: @Rev1.0 - I can now confirm - see above